# how to search the whole yii webapp?

Tags: php, search, yii

I have a webapp build with Yii framework, I want to add a search box to make a search overall the website including the dynamic pages (data from database) and the static pages (data in the file itself).

When I searched for some extensions, I found Zend Lucene, but I didn't like its mechanism, so do you suggest any other extensions that can do such search methods? in case that there is no extension better than Lucene, could you give some tutorials and examples?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). You then use the Solr's Data Importer Handler to import your data into a Solr/Lucene index. From your PHP code, you can use [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/). It is a nice PHP client to communicate with Solr. I always do that for my work.